# Question with eight eight numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, soft-question, open-problem

Suppose we have eight $8$ and we have to reach $1000$ with eight $8$. Use $+ \space 
 - \space \times \space \div \space \sqrt{} \space \cdots $ to reach $1000$.
Please help me to find at least one more possible solution except that I will write below.
$$8 \space \square \space  8 \space \square \space8 \space \square \space8 \space \square \space8 \space \square \space8 \space \square \space8 \space \square \space8 \space =1000 $$ 
one possible solution,that i found
$$888+88+8+8+8=1000$$

$***$ Parenthesis is allowed. Rationals allowed. Integer division allowed. Exponents allowed. Factorials allowed. 
but I got stuck to find more.
Thanks for any solution or hint in advance.

Comment: $(8888-888)/8$ ?

Comment: @ guest :very nice . thank you

Comment: perhaps u should explicitly state we can use concatenation

Comment: If anything, this question should be posted on [Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: My downvote for insufficient specifications. Order of execution ? Parenthesis allowed ? Rationals allowed ? Integer division allowed ? Exponents allowed ? Factorials allowed ? Meaning of $\cdots$ ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really about mathematics.  This is a puzzle and would be much more appropriate for [puzzling.se].

Comment: "easy but hard question" ? Please choose another title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
1000&=(8+8)\times 8\times \sqrt{8\times 8}-8-8-8\\
&=8\times 8\times8\times\sqrt{\sqrt{8+8}}-8-8-8\\
&=88\times 88\div 8+8\times \sqrt{8+8}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

If allowed to use exponents, another solution is:

$$1000=(8+(8+8)\div8)^{\sqrt{\sqrt{8+8}}+8\div8}$$

Answer (score 2):

$8×(8×(8+8)-\dfrac{8+8+8}{8})$

Comment: ¿Por que la vota de bajo?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of solutions.  For example:

$$ \eqalign{1000 &= 8 \cdot( 8 \cdot 8 + 8 \cdot 8) - (8+8+8)\cr
&= (8+8)\cdot(8 \cdot 8 - \frac{8+8}{8}) + 8\cr
&= ((8 + 8) \cdot 8 - \frac{8}{8}) \cdot 8 - (8 + 8)}$$